# Angular material calendar to display labels on specific dates

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material calendar and i want to add labels to a specific dates in mat-calendar, its working good but i want to show some labels on specific dates. To get idea about the view see below image.[image: dates_with_labels_calendar]

i have tried to implement something like highlighting certain dates with background-color, unfortunately its not the requirement to see it please go through below image.[image: Highlighted_calender]

is there a way to achieve this? if its please help me and help would be appreciated, please go through below code.

ex.html:->

```
  <mat-calendar opened [selected]="date" [dateClass]="dateClass()">
  </mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
```

ex.ts:->

```
dateClass() {
  return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    if (date.getDate() === 21 || date.getDate() === 23) {
      return 'special-date';
    } 
    else{
      return ;
    }
  };
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It's difficult manange a mat-calendar: mat-calendar only allow add css to the "days". It's true you can use pseudoelements `:after` to get it. I spend some time making a stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyo4a8-oxmewm?file=app%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.css, but I surrender. I think that your best bet is use ng-bootstrap datepicker: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview or create your own calendar:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943990/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-custom-datepicker-without-using-angular-material-or/59945162#59945162

Comment: @Eliseo you are correct, but as per client requirement i should use only material elements here, they want full application in angular material(UI) and angular(for functionalities) and as per you're suggestion if i use ng-bootstrap look and feel would change because we are using mat-calendar through out application, so i don't want to use ng-bootstrap. i appreciate that was very nice touch for my question and if u spend some more time on it, i think u would finish it successfully. you are almost there and thanks for the help.

Comment: @pk_teckie do you perhaps have an updated sample that uses a date range? your labels are only for a certain day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Eliseo for the help. small modification i have done here to reach the requirement and settled with following output and it looks like below.[image: Calendar Image]

here i have removed hover effect of calendar on dates to give good look, i hope its giving.

here is working example [Modified Calendar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyo4a8-xbdcc4?file=app%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.ts)

And thank you once again for the help.

Comment: Looking at the dateClass attribute, i am wondering if there is any way to set styles dynamically instead of css class because the colors here are static. and is it doable to have 2 labels in 1 date?