# Angular Holiday calendar application

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular(still learning), I'm solving hands-on for the holiday calendar application. I need a suggestion
Generate the data for the 42 cells in the table based on the month(input)..and store that in class with the date.

And based on those 42 rows, I need to render the 42 cells grid in the DOM (6x7).

I tried generating the 42 rows in the DOM like below.. it seems it wrong approach.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row tr-row">
            <div class="col td-month">23</div>
            <div class="col td-month">24</div>
            <div class="col td-month">25</div>
            <div class="col td-month">26</div>
            <div class="col td-month">27</div>
            <div class="col td-month">28</div>
            <div class="col td-month">29</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tr-row">
            <div class="col td-month">01</div>
            <div class="col td-month">02</div>
            <div class="col td-month">03</div>
            <div class="col td-month">04</div>
            <div class="col td-month">05</div>
            <div class="col td-month">06</div>
            <div class="col td-month">07</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tr-row">
            <div class="col td-month">08</div>
            <div class="col td-month">09</div>
            <div class="col td-month">10</div>
            <div class="col td-month">11</div>
            <div class="col td-month">12</div>
            <div class="col td-month">13</div>
            <div class="col td-month">14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tr-row">
            <div class="col td-month">15</div>
            <div class="col td-month">16</div>
            <div class="col td-month">17</div>
            <div class="col td-month">18</div>
            <div class="col td-month">19</div>
            <div class="col td-month">20</div>
            <div class="col td-month">21</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tr-row">
            <div class="col td-month">22</div>
            <div class="col td-month">23</div>
            <div class="col td-month">24</div>
            <div class="col td-month">25</div>
            <div class="col td-month">26</div>
            <div class="col td-month">27</div>
            <div class="col td-month">28</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tr-row">
            <div class="col td-month">29</div>
            <div class="col td-month">30</div>
            <div class="col td-month">31</div>
            <div class="col td-month">1</div>
            <div class="col td-month">2</div>
            <div class="col td-month">3</div>
            <div class="col td-month">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please suggest to me. I am stuck here.

Comment: If you don'w feel confortable with any existing calendar, take a look to this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943990/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-custom-datepicker-without-using-angular-material-or/59945162#59945162

Answer (score 0):

How about using an existing calendar, and adding it to your project? If there is an existing implementation from a reliable library, it is often a good practice to use those, since they themselves have already done the testing etc. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't need to :-)

Some existing calendars are:

- [PrimeNg's Full Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14-lts/fullcalendar)
- [PrimeNg's Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14-lts/calendar)
- [Angular Material DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

See if any of these suit your needs, and save yourself the need to re-implement an existing option