# How to get number of input fields according to number of days in specific month in calendar via angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking for designing calendar like design in Angular, in which I will get number of input fields according to number of days in that months

I want to show total addition of number of input fields for rows and columns in vertical and horizontal line : [image: example image]

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943990/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-custom-datepicker-without-using-angular-material-or/59945162#59945162) you have an example to create a "calendar". You can use this "structure" to show an "input" if `day.isMonth` or empty if not

Comment: yeah, you are correct if it a calendar. but, that is not, what I'm expecting