# Example to implement a horizontal monthly calendar for Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am searching for an example that implements a horizontal calendar with all days of the months in one line. Below is an example of what the table looks like.

```
weekd: | M | T | W | T | F | ...
mdate: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ...
Events:|   |   |   | x | x | ...
```

I am not able to find any examples of how to implement the horizontal calendar, which is why I am seeking help if anyone has implemented the same. This calendar will display all the events from that month as per the days listed in the month that can be edited on the click of an event, and we can navigate to the left and right to change any month. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943990/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-custom-datepicker-without-using-angular-material-or/59945162#59945162) you have how create manually a calendar. Just change the .css to place inline the days, You can also not display the days when !day.isMonth